# Can I animate the size||color of an NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, nsattributedstring

I have a string like "Points (67)" that is displayed on a label.

Sometimes in my app, the points total can change, via an NSNotification.

So, perhaps it will change to "Points (117)". I don't want this to happen instantly, as the user's eye is likely to miss the change. I'd like them to notice.

I would like to just animate the 67 to 117 part. Possibly the size, maybe growing by 10% as it changes, then shrinking back down 10% to original size. Or perhaps the color. Preferably size, but I'm guessing that's not possible without creating additional labels.

Is this doable?

Comment: are u asking for font size?

Answer (score 1):

You cant animate the Font size ,But yes u can scale the UILabel through which you can achieve your goal.

Below are two ways through which you show changes in UILabel font sizes.

**UIView Animation**

```
[UIView transitionWithView:yourlabel duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{

    yourlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0];

    }];
```

**Scale Animation**

```
CABasicAnimation*scaleAnimation[CABasicAnimationanimationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.xy"];
scaleAnimation.fromValue = @(1);
scaleAnimation.toValue = @00.5;
scaleAnimation.duration = self.animationDuration;

[yourlabel addAnimation:self.animationGroup forKey:@"pulse"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following animation to make user to notice the change:

```
[label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
 {
     [label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)];
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     if(finished)
     {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^
          {
              [label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)];
              label.text = @"Points (117)";
          }];
     }

 }];
```

You can change duration and scale as per your requirement....

Hope this will help you.